# Error "An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback"

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, argparse

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, random, argparse
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
```

Getting an error when running the below code

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Creates a photomosaic from input images')
parser.add_argument('--target', dest='target', required=True, help="Image to create mosaic from")
parser.add_argument('--images', dest='images', required=True, help="Diectory of images")
parser.add_argument('--grid', nargs=2, dest='grid', required=True, help="Size of photo mosaic")
parser.add_argument('--output', dest='output', required=False)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Error

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] --target TARGET --images IMAGES --grid GRID
                             GRID [--output OUTPUT]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: --target, --images, --grid
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

Please let me what change to be made to the above code.

I read that exit should not be made, however, I haven't used that in my code anywhere

Comment: please also post how you are calling it from the cmd line

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, random, argparse
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np`

Comment: Are you trying to run this via `jupyter` or as/in a `jupyter  notebook`.  That's what the `ipykernel` bit implies.  You can't pass commandline values to a script that way.  The error message says that you need to provide values like `--target` etc.  Do you even know what we mean by commandline values?